# Button click not working in GeckoFX (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gecko, geckofx

I have some button on page, click command not navigate page.

Debug console writes "IsWindowModal" Any ideas to solve this? Thanks

```
GeckoElementCollection link2 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (GeckoHtmlElement item in link2)
{
    string aux = item.GetAttribute("onclick");
    if (aux != null && aux != "" && aux.Contains("form1"))
    {
          item.Click();
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the expected inner html of the element that you are trying to click?

Comment: <input class="newInputButton" type="button" name="btnSubmit" width="100%" value="Hizmet Listesi (HTML)" onclick="javascript: form1.action='/WPEB/amp/bordrolisteOnayli?n=0';         form1.target='_blank';    form1.submit();">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the 'onclick' event rather than trying to click programmatically.

```
    string aux = item.GetAttribute("onclick");
    if (aux != null && aux != "" && aux.Contains("form1"))
    {
          DomEventArgs ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("MouseEvent");
          Event webEvent = new Event(browser.Window.DomWindow, ev.DomEvent as nsISupports);
          webEvent.InitEvent("click", true, false);
          item.DispatchEvent(ev);
     }
```